# Python, have a process run in the background and get status from the main thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing

this is a noob question, I have never done much in Python. I need to have a main process run and do stuff, while a background process does other calculations and saves the result to a variable. When the main thread wants, it should be able to read the last value stored in the variable: every value stored before is forgotten. Say that the background process is counting: I want to know what number it is at at this very moment. Here's a dummy code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import os
import time

def f(queue):
    a=0
    while True:
        a=a+1
        child_conn.send(a)
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        print(parent_conn.recv())
        time.sleep(1)
```

So the main thread prints the variable of the background thread every second, which is updated 10 times a second. 
I have tried with Pipe and Queue, but I do not get the last stored variable. This output is 1,2,3,4,... while I want to get 10,20,30,... (or similar, depending on timing). The problem here is that it, as the name suggests, works as a queue.

What I would do in java is create something like an asynctask and have it update a public variable, but my understanding is that multi processes cannot share variables.

What's the proper way of doing this with Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), which is implemented with shared memory between the processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

def f(n):
    while True:
        n.value += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = Value('i',0)
    p = Process(target=f, args=(n,))
    p.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(n.value)
```

Output:

```
7
17
26
35
44
53
```